# How to combine 2D-tiled datasets by coordinates in xarray

Tags: python, numpy, gis, python-xarray

I'm working on a project where I need to combine different sets of geographic image tiles into one large tile in Xarray. I am running into an issue. I've made a simplified example bellow.

```py
square1 = xr.DataArray(name="box1", data=np.random.randint(5, size=(3, 2)), coords=[("x", [0,1,2]),('y',[0,1])])
square2 = xr.DataArray(name="box2", data=np.random.randint(5, size=(3, 2)), coords=[("x", [3,4,5]),('y',[0,1])])
square3 = xr.DataArray(name="box3", data=np.random.randint(5, size=(3, 2)), coords=[("x", [0,1,2]),('y',[2,3])])
square4 = xr.DataArray(name="box4", data=np.random.randint(5, size=(3, 2)), coords=[("x", [3,4,5]),('y',[2,3])])

combineddata = xr.combine_by_coords([square1,square2,square3,square4])
```

I thought this is all you need to do it but I get this error

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-fc5add80d55a> in <module>
----> 1 xr.combine_by_coords([square1,square2,square3,square4])

~/my-conda-envs/dem/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xarray/core/combine.py in combine_by_coords(datasets, compat, data_vars, coords, fill_value, join, combine_attrs)
    713 
    714     # Group by data vars
--> 715     sorted_datasets = sorted(datasets, key=vars_as_keys)
    716     grouped_by_vars = itertools.groupby(sorted_datasets, key=vars_as_keys)
    717 

~/my-conda-envs/dem/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xarray/core/combine.py in vars_as_keys(ds)
    502 
    503 def vars_as_keys(ds):
--> 504     return tuple(sorted(ds))
    505 
    506 

~/my-conda-envs/dem/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xarray/core/common.py in __bool__(self)
    118 
    119     def __bool__(self: Any) -> bool:
--> 120         return bool(self.values)
    121 
    122     def __float__(self: Any) -> float:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xarray `combine_by_coords` currently only works for xarray Dataset objects, not DataArray objects. See this issue: https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/3248.  The workaround provided there by @dcherian is to convert the DataArrays to Datasets, combine, and then convert back to a DataArray.

So this works:

```py
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

square1 = xr.DataArray(name="box", data=np.random.randint(5, size=(3, 2)), coords=[("x", [0,1,2]),('y',[0,1])]) 
square2 = xr.DataArray(name="box", data=np.random.randint(5, size=(3, 2)), coords=[("x", [3,4,5]),('y',[0,1])]) 
square3 = xr.DataArray(name="box", data=np.random.randint(5, size=(3, 2)), coords=[("x", [0,1,2]),('y',[2,3])]) 
square4 = xr.DataArray(name="box", data=np.random.randint(5, size=(3, 2)), coords=[("x", [3,4,5]),('y',[2,3])]) 

combineddata = xr.combine_by_coords(sq.to_dataset() for sq in [square1,square2,square3,square4]).to_array()
```